# jQuery not responding to timed events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im having trouble getting my second function to react to the changes the first function brings.

```
   var jumbotron = function(){
    var jumbotronCounter = 1
    var jumbotronSwitch = function(){
        var jumbotronTimer = function(){
        jumbotronCounter++
        }
        jumbotronTimer();
        if (jumbotronCounter > 3){
            jumbotronCounter = 1
        }
        console.log(jumbotronCounter);
    }
    setInterval(jumbotronSwitch,7000);

    var jumbotronListener = function(){
    if(jumbotronCounter = 1){
        console.log('first');
    }else if(jumbotronCounter = 2){
        console.log('second');
    }else if(jumbotronCounter = 3){
        console.log('third');
    }
    };
    jumbotronListener();
}

jumbotron();
```

Id like to use "jumbotronListener" to run some code when "jumbotronCounter" changes

Comment: I think jumbotronListener is only running once, but not sure. If so, how can I get it to run indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jumbotronListener` is indeed only running once. You can, instead, run it every time the interval runs:

```
var jumbotron = function () {
    var jumbotronCounter = 1;
    var jumbotronSwitch = function () {
        var jumbotronTimer = function () {
            jumbotronCounter++;
        };
        jumbotronTimer();
        if (jumbotronCounter > 3) {
            jumbotronCounter = 1;
        }
        // Execute the listener every time the interval runs
        jumbotronListener();
        console.log(jumbotronCounter);
    };
    setInterval(jumbotronSwitch, 7000);

    // Run for the first time if you wish:
    jumbotronListener();

    // Set this as function so you can 'use it before declaring it'
    function jumbotronListener() {
        // You had invalid operators. = assigns and === compares (strictly)
        if(jumbotronCounter === 1) {
            console.log('first');
        } else if(jumbotronCounter === 2) {
            console.log('second');
        } else if(jumbotronCounter === 3) {
            console.log('third');
        }
    }
};

jumbotron();
```

You also had some missing semicolons in there, sometimes it's not a problem since JavaScript auto-inserts them, but sometimes it is, so it's a good idea to always make sure to *manually* insert them where they go.

Comment: some of those `if()` operators are invalid

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to change them. Thanks.